# Split-View Master displays black cell when rotated

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, autorotate

I'm using a splitview controller and when I turn the orientation from portrait to landscape orientation with a popover displayed, my new master view has a black bar between the first cell of my tableview and the nav bar. I am calling to dismiss the popover before rotation - and it is working. If however I dismiss the popover in view before rotating, I don't get this black bar?? Is this a sign of a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an indication of a memory leak. It's an indication of not handling rotation correctly. You haven't posted any code, so it's very hard to tell you what you're doing wrong. If you would post the code it would also be easier to rule out memory leak.